# printing complex number matrix in jupyter more beautiful

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to find a way to display complex numpy matrices in jupyter more beautiful.
The pandas Dataframe works pretty nice for rational floating point number. However when using complex numbers the precision is too high so the table will expand way too much. I tried to set the display precision with `set_option()` but it doesn't work. Here is an Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option("display.precision", 3)

A = np.random.rand(3,3)
df_A = pd.DataFrame(A)

B = np.random.rand(3,3)+1j*np.random.rand(3,3)
df_B = pd.DataFrame(B)

print(df_A)
print(df_B)
```

Output:

```
    0      1      2
0  0.665  0.824  0.953
1  0.341  0.078  0.408
2  0.945  0.411  0.078
                                            0  \
0    (0.2553045397887609+0.8464631779709604j)   
1  (0.5724405361700162+0.047300152111596105j)   
2     (0.5824766758024993+0.974755917539835j)   

                                           1  \
0  (0.3533797280121552+0.20515824034905894j)   
1    (0.928312255311234+0.3909443194373995j)   
2   (0.2700966337410404+0.9137483492310767j)   

                                           2  
0  (0.21748538025578568+0.7730350615682122j)  
1  (0.2435709287109903+0.46366472945887327j)  
2   (0.6531622218102532+0.5102462678094016j)
```

so you see that the rational floating point matrix is printed with the right precision but the complex matrix is not affected by it.

Is that a bug or a feature?
Is there a way to reduce the precision displayed also for complex numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use basic string formatting inside `applymap`.

```
df_B = df_B.applymap('{:.3f}'.format)
df_B
               0               1               2
0   0.976+0.935j    0.739+0.851j    0.436+0.734j
1   0.998+0.867j    0.774+0.849j    0.553+0.749j
2   0.405+0.049j    0.965+0.912j    0.292+0.958j
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. However looks really cumbersome to apply this for every single matrix. Is a for-loop really necessary to solve this problem? Would be nice to have a statement that I have to type one time that applies for all complex matrices I want to print.

Comment: @jay_pee_ `applymap` on rescue.